# How can I show that $\lim_{x \rightarrow 0} \frac {4x^2}{e^{\frac {6}{x}}} = 0$.

Tags: calculus, limits

How can I show that $$\lim_{x \rightarrow 0} \frac {4x^2}{e^{\frac {6}{x}}} = 0$$

My thoughts are that I may need to use L'Hs Rule and possibly have to take logs to deal with the exponent which is a function of $x $.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you mean $x \to 0^+$, then you have $$ \lim_{x \to 0^+}e^{6/x}=\infty $$ thus $$ \lim_{x \to   0^+}\frac{4x^2}{e^{6/x}}=\lim_{x \to   0^+}4x^2\times \lim_{x \to   0^+}\frac1{e^{6/x}}=0 \times \frac1{\infty}=0 $$

If you consider $x \to 0^-$, then the limit is $+\infty$.

Answer (score 1):

Define the function $$f:\mathbb{R}^+\to \mathbb{R},\ f(x)=2\ln x-6/x$$ Then, basically your limit becomes $$4\exp(\lim_{x\to 0+}f(x))=4\exp(-\infty)=0$$